# How can i reduce the initial loading time in angular 7 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

Actually my angular 7 app is taking so much time time to load (above 5 mins) the first page (especially at first opening the website app)

I have tried many things including Optimization a mentioned below but its doesnt work

```
 node --max_old_space_size=18192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build 
--prod --build-optimizer
```

Expected result :
The website should load within 1 sec

Actual result :
It is getting loaded after 5 mins
Please help

Comment: This is too broad, we don't have any insights of what's going on within your code and what's causing the 5 min load.

Comment: Hi dino,  Its beacuse main.js contains around 10MB to load so only its taking time is there any way to reduce the file size

Answer (score 0):

can you use AOT ? if yes, you can try:

```
ng build --aot --optimization=true --prod=true --build-optimizer=true --progress=true
```

With this config and lazy loading I have 500ko chunks and 500ms max load time

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use Lazy Loading Feature Modules.

This method load the pages when are called by url, so the initial page load more faster.

[+ Info](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Maybe you can change your folder structure and split it in modules like [this](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7)

Comment: Thanks eduardo  but is there any other way to get rid because
Lazy loading feature will take more time to complete

Comment: There can be number of reasons why initial load takes a long time. But to start with, avoid loading all modules in one go by introducing lazy loading modules. I have always used preloadingStrategy to preload all modules (https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules)  in combination with lazy loading, which is efficient. If this is taken care of, then I would inspect in the browser to find out which specific network call takes time (it could be one of your API or js module etc) so you can narrow down your issue to improve the performance.

Comment: yaa its beacuse main.js contains areound 10MB to load so only its taking time is there any way to reduce the file size